# Why is my z-index not working in this code?

Tags: html, css, z-index, styling

I have a website here with a sidebar, but I want the sidebar to be hidden until the user clicks on a menu button. Anyways, my `.sidebar` is on `z-index: 0;` while my `.page-content` is on `z-index: 1;`. Why is the sidebar not hidden when I load the webpage? I have nothing in my `page-content` except for a `<h1>` for testing purposes.

Here is my `HTML` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    <div class = "page-wrapper">

        <div class = "page-content">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>

        <div class = "sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li>#</li>
                <li>#</li>
                <li>#</li>
                <li>#</li>
                <li>#</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `CSS` file:

```
h1 {
    /* Just to centre my text */
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.page-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

So why isn't my sidebar being hidden when I load the webpage? When I load this, I can see the sidebar and the "Test" text both.

EDIT:

I see many of you have said that the `z-index` is not for hiding stuff. I am not trying to hide the sidebar. When the user clicks on the menu button, I want the page to slide over to reveal the sidebar, hence the reason I am using the `z-index` and not `display: none;`.

EDIT:

Some of you have said that this is a duplicate from another question, but when you read my comments, please realize that the question I am asking, is quite different. I am going to try to explain what I am attempting to do here as simply as I can. I have a website, where a user clicks on the menu bar, the entire website transitions 180px to the right, thus revealing the sidebar that is fixed underneath. You guys mentioned that my `.page-content` needs a background, but like someone else said, it only takes up my background as big as the objects inside are. How or where can I set a background that will move, yet still cover the sidebar completely?

Comment: the z-index works,but the 2 relevant divs should overlap if you want to see different z levels at work

Comment: Use `display: none` to make an element not visible and not take up space. The z-index doesn't hide an element but specify position on the z-index.

Comment: instead of using z-index you should use opacity=0

Comment: where is your script to hide the {sidebar} or using CSS to hide ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Absolute and fixed positioning together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190674/absolute-and-fixed-positioning-together)

Comment: Are you sure? Take in mind that your page container background, acording that css, is transparent. So even if your sidebar is correctly positioned over page container, you will continue seeig it except for regions covered by opaque objects in sidebar…

Comment: You have no background on your page-content, so it is over the sidebar, it just doesn't have any background

Comment: @Raj I am using `CSS` to move my page content. Please read my second edit for a clearer view on what I intend to accomplish.

Comment: @YannChabot Please read my second edit...

Comment: @bitifet Please read my second edit...

Comment: If the height and width of your element is set to 100% in CSS, it will take 100%... of your screen (so not your document). moving it to the right will reveal the left sidebar.

Comment: @YannChabot Could you clarify which element I have to set the height and width for?

Comment: On your page content.

Comment: @YannChabot Ok, yes that seems to fix it. Would you like to post an answer so that I can mark the problem as resolved?

Comment: Done my friend! hope it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidebar is not hidden because your .page-content doesn't have a background. Put a background and add this CSS:

```
  .page-content{
     background: #fff;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
  }
```

This way, you'll be able to slide it to then side afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your `z-index` **IS** working.

`z-index` is not responsible for making an element visible or not. (For that, you can use the `opacity`,`visibility`, or `display` properties.

`z-index` can be used to position elements **behind** other elements with opaque backgrounds, which may make them appear hidden (pun intended), but rest assured, the element is still there.

Your CSS has no elements with opaque backgrounds with `z-indicies` higher than `0` that sit on top of `.sidebar`, so that's why you see it.

Comment: Ok I see, but when I add a white background to the `page-content` item, I only get this white line, and the rest I can still see the side bar. Where would I put my background?

Comment: That's because, as per your CSS, `.page-content` is only as tall as it needs to be, which is the height of it's `h1` child - so it's not tall enough to cover up `.sidebar`. If your goal is to make your `sidebar` hidden, you should be using `visibility: hidden`

Comment: How can I make my `.page-content` as big as my webpage? You see, I want the sidebar to stay fixed, then when the user clicks the menu button, I want the website to transition 180px to the right, thus revealing the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Add background to .page-content you will see the z-index's effect.

A better approach would be to hide the side bar with left property as some negative value, for example -100px as below.

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: #333;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

and when the user clicks the menu icon set left: 0px using javascript.

Comment: Yes, that is the way that I originally did it but I wanted to make that the sidebar is under the page, and then gets revealed as the page moves to the right. I want the side bar to stay fixed the entire time.